# Changing value of input while being in an echo

Tags: php, html, input

I wanted to change the value of several  elements by clicking the row of one of my list elements

my inputs

```
<legend> current Song </legend>
        <p>
            <label>Id </label>
            <input type = "text"
                   id = "currentId"
                   value = ""/>
        </p>
        //like 12 more of them with the same format as these 
        <p>
            <label>Paragraphs</label>
            <textarea id="currentParagraph"
                      rows="10"
                      cols="80"></textarea>
        </p>
```

my code for the table atm:

```
        <table>
            <thead>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($editor->lieder);$i++)
            {
              echo "<tr onclick=\" if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
                    {
                    
                    }
                    \">";

              echo "<td>".$editor->lieder[$i]['number']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$editor->lieder[$i]['name']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$editor->lieder[$i]['category']."</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I'm not sure how to set the inputs from inside the if because already some layers into it but it's the only way I think of to realise my idea

Comment: I'm having a tough time understanding what you want this code to do or what the issue is. Can you please elaborate? What inputs are you talking about (the ones from the first snippet)? Where do these inputs need to go?

Comment: the inputs should work as some form of an editor so when I click a row in the table it sets the values to the text I specifically connect to that row and later I work out some kind of save button to save the changes made but I'm still searching for a way to set the values of the different inputs while being in that "if"